# How can i get data to be pushed from the database to the client, like a messenger service?

Tags: php, android, mysql, push, messenger

I am trying to code a messenger service that will store sent messages in a server and then push the message to all devices connected to the server.

The messenger will be used in a classroom environment and the messages will never be sent to one individual device. At the moment a message can be sent and stored in the database but the app needs to be refreshed for all the messages to be displayed. A simple way would be to continuously run the stored procedure but that would require extra bandwidth and i'm sure there is a better way to do it.

I am currently coding in Android Studio and I'm using MySQL as my database and PHP for my stored procedures. I am very new at Java and this type of coding so any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: sockets, if its a web-application use web-sockets, otherwise you can create a custom socket for your application.  do some googling on the subject.

Comment: also, n.b. PHP is not very good for sockets, as it was never designed to be a consistent process, you should use Python or Java for socket applications.

Comment: or use GCM-http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Comment: You should really checkout: https://www.firebase.com/

It's designed to achieve what you want in an easy way. It has bindings for Android (and other platforms).

Comment: @RaggaMuffin-420 Im only using PHP for the query statements, the rest is in Java. I googled Sockets and it seems to be what i'm looking for, but i'm going to look into GCM as well because it seems like an interesting option to look into.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what you are suggesting is named "polling" => check if the server has some updates each 10sec or something like that.  You're right, it's evil (drains the battery, use a lot of bad=ndwidth, etc.)

What you need is a "push" service. If you are working with Android, the easiest way of doing it is to use GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) : http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

This little guy will provide you a way of notifying all the devices that theure have been some changes on the server.

It's pretty well done (if it can't reach the devices, it will try again with an exponential time delay, etc.).

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely check it out!

Answer (score 0):

You can use google cloud messaging service to send notification in device so please register your application on google service all step are cover below link. 
Open below link and follow step

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/