# How to connec a mySQL server to an android application via sockets

Tags: java, android, mysql, sockets

I previously asked a question about pushing data from a database(mySQL) to an android messenger app, and was told to use sockets.[How can i get data to be pushed from the database to the client, like a messenger service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25123025/how-can-i-get-data-to-be-pushed-from-the-database-to-the-client-like-a-messenge) After a day of research and a bit of trial and error, iv finally found a tutorial that does what i need, but instead of using java, it runs on HTML.

The HTML code is used to basically display whats being sent from the database. In my case i'm retrieving data from the database through a stored procedure in NetBeans using PHP, and then filling a ListView with the data, so instead of using the table like in the tutorial, i need someway of refreshing my app and loading the new data into the listview.

My question is, how would i implement the same HTML code or java equivalent in my app.

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <time></time>
    <div id="container">Loading ...</div>
<script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>

    // create a new websocket
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000');
    // on message received we print all the data inside the #container div
    socket.on('notification', function (data) {
    var usersList = "<dl>";
    $.each(data.users,function(index,user){
        usersList += "<dt>" + user.user_name + "</dt>\n" +
                     "<dd>" + user.user_description + "\n" +
                     "<figure> <img class='img-polaroid' width='50px' src='" + user.user_img + "' /></figure>"                    
                     "</dd>";
    });
    usersList += "</dl>";
    $('#container').html(usersList);

    $('time').html('Last Update:' + data.time);
  });
</script>
<div id="Div1">Complete</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The rest of the tutorial just shows how to set up the socket server as a javascript file, which iv managed to get running, the code and whole tutorial can be found here: http://www.gianlucaguarini.com/blog/push-notification-server-streaming-on-a-mysql-database/

Comment: In java create a socket and use the observer design pattern to fire then changes and report it to the display\gui (like what jquery is doing)

Comment: Sorry i should have been more clear on that part. This app will be on multiple devices, all linked to one server. So when one person sends a message, they all should receive it. Follow the link to my previous question to get a better feel for what the app does.

Comment: observer pattern is the best way:
User makes change 
Server (observer 1) notes change sends out update to client(s)
Client(s) handles update

Comment: I originally thought of the observer pattern, because it fits what i want to do, but I wouldn't even know where to begin implementing it on multiple devices. Iv used the pattern once with a small C# program and that's about it! so any further help from your side would be appreciated.

Comment: Java you have to use interfaces read this:
http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/12/observer-design-pattern-java-example.html
Each language should follow a similar pattern with slight variation based on the limitations of the language. Under stand the pattern is psudo code will help implement across multiple languages

Comment: Pretty much the same concept as C#, so ill look into it! Thanks for the help.